# @eval escapes $ in @testset name argument

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

I have several `@testset`s in a file and I want to align the output of them.
At first it looks like this:

```
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
short         |    1      1
Test Summary:         | Pass  Total
test with longer name |    1      1
```

I want the `|` aligned so that it goes like this:

```
Test Summary:         | Pass  Total
short                 |    1      1
Test Summary:         | Pass  Total
test with longer name |    1      1
```

I tried using `@sprintf` to make the names the same length, but the `@testset` macro needs a string literal. So I used `@eval` to interpolate a formatted string into the name:

```
testName(name) = @sprintf("%-25s", name)

@eval begin

@testset $(testName("short")) begin
    @test true
end

@testset $(testName("test with longer name")) begin
    @test true
end

end # @eval
```

This gives me what I want for simple testsets, but falls short on ones with `for`
loop variables interpolated into the name.
If I add a test like this:

```
@testset $(testName("some for test \$i")) for i in 9:11
    @test i > 0
end
```

the output is

```
Test Summary:             | Pass  Total
short                     |    1      1
Test Summary:             | Pass  Total
test with longer name     |    1      1
Test Summary:             | Pass  Total
some for test $i          |    1      1
Test Summary:             | Pass  Total
some for test $i          |    1      1
Test Summary:             | Pass  Total
some for test $i          |    1      1
```

It looks like the eval macro escapes the `$` somehow and it no longer works with the `@testset` macro.
Why doesn't it work and how can I force the `$` to exist unescaped in the name string literal? (suggestions on how to align the results also welcome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String` with interpolation as the argument to `@testset` macro:

```
julia> @testset "$(testName("some for test $i"))" for i in 9:11
           @test i > 0
       end;
Test Summary:             | Pass  Total
some for test 9           |    1      1
Test Summary:             | Pass  Total
some for test 10          |    1      1
Test Summary:             | Pass  Total
some for test 11          |    1      1
```